# Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, nuget

Пишу проект в Visual Studio (Community 2019) на C# с использованием ServiceStack.Redis. Поскольку C#, сижу на Win 10 (Redis под винду есть, но очень старый, и, боюсь, что в этом может и заключаться проблема)
Вот выдержка из кода:

```
public class PeopleStorage: IDisposable
{
    public PeopleStorage()
    {
        redisManager = new RedisManagerPool("localhost");
        redis = (RedisClient)redisManager.GetClient();
        facts = (RedisTypedClient<List<Fact>>)redis.As<List<Fact>>();
    }

    public List<Fact> GetFacts(int id)
    {
        string sid = id.ToString();
        if (facts.ContainsKey(sid))
            return facts[sid];
        return accessor.GetFacts(id);
    }

    private RedisTypedClient<List<Fact>> facts;
    private RedisClient redis;
    private RedisManagerPool redisManager;
}
```

При попытке обращения к базе данных по ключу в строчке `return facts[sid];` возникает исключение:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: "Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку
> "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" либо одну из их
> зависимостей. Найденное определение манифеста сборки не соответствует
> ссылке на сборку. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

Пробовал обновлять все пакеты, начиная от serviceStack'овских, заканчивая самим System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe. Причем в NuGet нельзя выбрать версию 4.0.4.1, близжайше, что там есть - 4.0.0, а актуальная и используемая - вообще 4.0.7.
Я не понимаю, почему он обращается именно к этой версии и как можно исправить эту проблему
Не помогла даже полная переустановка Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

Получил [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62764744/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-compilerservices-unsafe/62770487#62770487) на англоязычном stackoverflow:

> Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe

Похоже,что вы установили пакет nuget System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe версии 4.5.3. И это соответствует сборке System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe версии 4.0.4.1.

**Предложения**

1. Попробуйте попробуйте зарегистрировать System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe версии 4.0.4.1 в GAC.

   - **Запустите командную строку разработчика для VS2019** от имени **Администратора**
   - введите:

     ```
      cd xxxxx (путь к System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe 4.0.4.1, это в bin/debug вашего проекта)

      gacutil /i System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
     ```

   *(Этот вариант мне помог, поэтому второй вариант я не пробовал)*
2. Если вы используете проект Net Framework с файлом xxx.config, можно использовать [bindingRedirect](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/bindingredirect-element). Добавьте в файл `app.config` или `web.config` следующее:

```xml
<configuration>  
    <runtime>  
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
            <dependentAssembly>  
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe"  
                                publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"  
                                culture="neutral" />  
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.4.1"  
                                newVersion="4.0.4.1"/>  
            </dependentAssembly>  
        </assemblyBinding>  
    </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

**К тому же**, если вы обновите пакет `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` до новой версии, вы также поменяете версию сборки bindingRedirect.

`4.5.x` - это версия пакета nuget `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe`, а `4.0.x.x` - это версия сборки `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll`.

```
4.5.0 is 4.0.4.0 
4.5.1 is 4.0.4.0 
4.5.2 is 4.0.4.0 
4.5.3 is 4.0.4.1
4.6.0 is 4.0.5.0
4.7.0 is 4.0.6.0
4.7.1 is 4.0.6.1
```

P.S. В другом ответе также была приведена [эта](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1128) ссылка на обсуждение (и решение) этой проблемы на github.